# How to Fade, Blur, Feather an Object Gradually with Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Think of a black triangle. How would I gradually fade this triangle top down, where the top point stays sharp/in-focus while gradually (fading, blurring, feathering) towards the triangle base?

Here's the best I could achieve with a faded clipping mask on an overlapping blurred second triangle. Doesn't look great. Ideally the triangle sides blur, fade evenly as they travel downward.
[image]

Comment: Add a gradient across stroke. Then scale it down at apex

Comment: That worked well, thanks. It's unfortunate Illustrator won't allow Gradient Across Stroke for outside or inside strokes.

Comment: Just offset the stroke in the effect. It might also work with variable width stokes. By the way if you write down what you edited to the answer field and write what you did you would get 20 points if not more. And we can clear the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the output looks like using the suggested Gradient Across Stroke and pinching the anchor at the apex with the Width Tool. I'm happy with these results.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The case becomes more tricky if the already presented gradient across stroke is for some reason unavailable (freeware, low cost vector drawing program or a legacy version).

There are fortunately other possibilities, but their availability varies between programs:

1. Radial blur in spin mode, the  spinning center is the apex of the triangle
2. Blend between 2 black triangles, the bigger one is fully transparent
3. Conical gradient, the center is the apex

Inkscape users have a form of blending which differs from what Illustrator provides. In Inkscape Extensions > Generate from Path > Interpolate generates intermediate versions between 2 paths which have different color or geometry or both.

Unfortunately Interpolation between fully opaque black triangle and fully transparent bigger black triangle gives an unexpected result - a bug or a well documented property? - no idea. It worked well in Illustrator.

Interpolate between a black triangle and a bigger white triangle gives the expected result, if both triangles are opaque:

[image]

There's 50 intermediate triangles. It's a big number, 10 could be enough for screen.

But the blurry edges are not transparent. One possible workaround which works just with this black-white color case is to use blending mode Multiply:

[image]

The group of triangles has blending mode Multiply. The background (= a rectangle filled with gradient white-red-blue-black) has blending mode Normal.